# Vector transformation for a general rotation

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

I know the three components of a vector, say $u_{x}$, $u_{y}$ and $u_{z}$ about a coordiante system prior to rotation. Their resultant gives me the vector $u_{res}$. The direction of this resultant vector is the direction of my new X axis, i.e. the X axis is rotated to align it along the resultant vector.

How do I find the components of any vector in this new coordinate system?

Comment: The information given does not uniquely determine a rotation.  However see the [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) which is a *reflection* determined a single vector (in any dimension).  It is often used to map a given vector $\vec x$ to the "axis" $e_1$, and the reverse mapping is given by the matrix transpose (since the Householder matrix is orthogonal).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I wanted to include an ugly illustration.

As it is, your question is probably underspecified, since there is an infinity of possible 3D rotations that can map the positive $x$-axis onto your (resultant) vector $\mathbf u$. If you only care about mapping the (old) $x$-axis onto a new direction, these infinite possibilities don't matter. But because you actually need to also figure out what your new $y$ and $z$-axes are, these infinite possibilities become a problem.

[image: One possible axes rotation]

Say your original axes are supported by the vectors $\mathbf i$, $\mathbf j$ and $\mathbf k$ (in red). One possible rotation that maps $\mathbf i$ onto $\mathbf u$ is represented by the solid black arc, and will map these vectors onto $\mathbf i'$, $\mathbf j'$ and $\mathbf k'$ (blue).

But if you pick another rotation that still maps $\mathbf i$ to $\mathbf u$, you will end up with completely different vectors $\mathbf j'$ and $\mathbf k'$ :

[image: Another possible axes rotation]

And different basis vectors imply different coordinates.

---

On a side note, if someone knows a good software to make simple 3D illustrations, I'd like some recommendations.